# example for <object> element in html

Tags: html, element

Could anyone show me an example, where used the  element for show video by using plugin in html file?? for example, how will work this code`

```
<object width = "320" height = "240" data= "BMW-M8.mp4" type= "video/mp4"  >
<param name= "autoplay" value= "true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if &lt IE9]>
<object width="480" height="280" 
classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" 
codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"> 
   <param name="src" value="myVideo.mp4" />
   <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
</object>
<![endif]-->
 
<video controls width="480" height="280">
   <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="myVideo.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

The object tag is hidden from modern browsers by a conditional comment. Older versions of Internet Explorer ignore the video tag.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If you can, please show an example, where used "plugin" by using <object> element.